# Case MySQL when off then on with other column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two columns:

```
reaction AND status
```

**Default TEXT on column status:**

```
off
```

**How to:**

```
            UPDATE profile_post SET    
            status = CASE                   
            WHEN 'off' THEN 'on', reaction +1
            WHEN 'on' THEN 'off', reaction -1
            END
            WHERE post = '$postid1'
```

I've been trying to use WHEN CASE but somehow it's giving me errors all the time.

Comment: What code did you try? Please show your attempt.

Comment: Show complete `SHOW CREATE TABLE profile_post;` output. Does `on` and `off` are the only possible values for `status`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating multiple values, so you can try something like this:

```
UPDATE profile_post SET
   reaction = reaction + 1,
   status = CASE
                 WHEN status  = 'off' THEN 'on'
                 WHEN status = 'on' THEN 'off'
                 ELSE 'on'

   END
WHERE post = '$postid1'
```

**EDIT**

In order to add a condition to the column 'reaction', like commented in the answer, please try this:

```
UPDATE profile_post SET
   reaction = CASE 
                WHEN status = 'off' THEN reaction + 1
                ELSE reaction - 1
              END,
   status = CASE
               WHEN status = 'on' THEN 'off'
               ELSE 'on'
            END
WHERE post = '$postid1'
```

Comment: Wrong. Imagine that initially `status = 'unknown'`...

Comment: If put a ELSE in the code, setting statatus on, maybe work

Comment: It worked. @Akina default for status is set always at off word by default.

Comment: Nice. But what @Akina told was right. If status was not set by 'on' or 'off' this going to mess up. Make sure that this not going to happen, or include the ELSE (already edited the answer)

Comment: Can you update @JohnathaRelvas this query to work with the reaction +1?
Like if status = off set reaction +1 ELSE if status = on set reaction -1? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Question says default status is 'off' so 'unknown' would not apply.

Comment: `UPDATE profile_post SET
       reaction = CASE
        status = 'off' THEN reaction + 1
        OR status = 'on' THEN reaction -1
       status = CASE
        WHEN status  = 'off' THEN 'on'
        WHEN status = 'on' THEN 'off'
       END;
    WHERE post = '$postid1'`

Comment: The first WHEN in the answer is unnecessary

Comment: @MarkB removed :)

Comment: @JohnathaRelvas my last try:

`UPDATE profile_post SET
      status = CASE
        WHEN status  = 'off' THEN 'on' AND reaction = reaction + 1
        WHEN status = 'on' THEN 'off' AND reaction = reaction -1
      END;`

Comment: so, you can try this code: `update profile_post SET
   reaction = CASE 
       WHEN status = 'off' then reaction + 1
                ELSE reaction - 1
   status = case
                 when status = 'on' then 'off'
                 ELSE 'on'
   end
WHERE post = '$postid1'`

Comment: @JohnathaRelvas did'nt work :(
My last:
    `status = CASE         
    WHEN 'off' THEN 'on', reaction +1
    ELSE 'on' THEN 'off', reaction -1`

Comment: if you can, comment here the message error that returns with the code I posted before

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'status = case when status = 'on' then 'off' ...' at line

Comment: The SQL in the comments has obvious typos.  Edit your answer and put the revised sql in there. By formatting across multiple lines you'll spot the typos.  *(such as `ELSE reaction - 1 status =` actually needing to be `ELSE reaction - 1 END, status =`)*

Comment: Great! Thanks to @MatBailie for clarify the error on the code